# what I did wrong with my accelerometer and canvas 2d? android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a 2d canvas with the accelerometer API.
The API full example works when I tilt the phone the acceleration.x and acceleration.y changes.
So I made a canvas 2d circle and implemented the acceleration.x and acceleration.y but when I did that, the circle is gone.

This is my html

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

This is my partial script

```
   function movingCircle (acceleration) {
            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            var x = acceleration.x;
            var y = acceleration.y;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, .5)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,20,0,2*Math.PI, true);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            c.innerHTML = 'testing';
       }
```

`ctx.arc(x,y,20,0,2*Math.PI, true);` if I change the x and y into 47.5, 25 then I can see my circle clearly positioned near the top left corner.

Anyone can give me a hand what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration's `x` & `y` keys are not absolute cordinates on which you can plot your circle. Acceleration is difference in velocity over time. So rather you them as quantities to add to your current circle position.

Something like: `x = x + acceleration.x;`